# Every permutation $\sigma$ of a finite set is a product of disjoint cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

I was trying to prove the following statement, however when I finished I realized that the proof of my book (*A first course in abstract algebra* by Fraleigh) actually holds in 3 lines.

Hence I doubt of the coherence of my proof since I had to prove an external claim I introduced myself in it, which made it ridiculously long.

I did so because I didn't know if I could assume this apparently obvious claim (since obvious doesn't mean  that it doesn't deserves to be proved).

> **9.8 Theorem** Every permutation $\sigma$ of a finite set is a product of disjoint cycles.

Let $A$ be a finite set and $\sigma\in S_A$ a permutation.

We firstly claim that the fact that A is finite implies that for every $a\in A$ there exists a $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sigma^n a = a$.

Suppose that it isn't the case, i.e. $\exists a\in A:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\sigma^n a \neq a$.

~

Let's consider the case when the images of $\sigma$ do not repeat themselves in $A$, i.e. $(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}^2, x\in A$
\begin{gather}
\sigma^i x = \sigma^j x \Leftrightarrow i=j
\end{gather}
Then, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sigma^n x$ is unique in $A$.

Let $\phi_x:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\phi_x a = n \Leftrightarrow a = \sigma^n x$.

Therefore,
\begin{gather}
\phi_x a = \phi_x b \Leftrightarrow a=b \\
\forall n \in\mathbb{N}:\exists a\in A, a=\sigma^n x \\
\Rightarrow \phi_x[A] = \mathbb{N}
\end{gather}
We observe that $\phi$ is consequently injective and surjective, so it is an isomorphism between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Therefore $A$ is not finite which is absurd.

~

Now let's consider the case when there's at least one repetition of the images of $\sigma$ in $A$.

Thus,
\begin{gather}
\exists \Gamma \subseteq A:\Gamma = \lbrace \sigma^n a \mid n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace \\
\Rightarrow \exists x \in\Gamma : x=\sigma^i a \wedge x=\sigma^j a,\text{ with }(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}^2:i\neq j
\end{gather}
Without loss of generality, let $j > i$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
\begin{gather}
\sigma^i a = \sigma^j a \\
\Rightarrow a = \sigma^{-i}\sigma^j a = \sigma^n a
\end{gather}
Which goes against our hypothesis.

Therefore, $\forall a \in A: \exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sigma^n a = a$.

~

Pick an $a\in A$.

We know that $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sigma^n a = a$.

Observe that $C_0=(a,\sigma a,...,\sigma^{n-1}a)$ is a cycle.

If there is a $b$ in $A$ such that $b$ isn't in $C_0$, repeat the operation until every element in $A$ belong in a unique cycle.

~

A is finite so there's a finite number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ of disjoint cycles.

Observe that
\begin{gather}
\sigma=C_0C_1...C_m
\end{gather}

Hence, every permutation $\sigma$ of a finite set is a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: Is your question about whether the proof of your "external" claim is correct?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz it's more about whether the proof as a whole is correct (which includes the "external" claim) since I doubt about the coherence of the entire proof. I don't know if I had to precise it but the proof of the external claim ends just before the "Pick an $a\in A$".

Comment: I'm sorry your proof is a little long for me to read because your external lemma is a bit long. However, there is a more conceptual way to frame your lemma which simplifies your proof greatly, while maintaining its overall exposition. Notice that your lemma is equivalent to the claim that every $\sigma\in S_A$ has finite order, meaning that for each $\sigma\in S_A$, there exists $n$ such that $\sigma^n = \mathrm{id}_A$. This is a statement which applies to any finite group, which dramatically simplifies things, and in particular frees you from looking at the cases for $\sigma$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz thanks for your comment. But, may you explain to me what does $\text{id}_A$ means?

Comment: $\mathrm{id}_A$ is the identity map of the set $A$ (which is also the identity element of the group $S_A$). You have the right idea for the second part of your proof, by the way, taking elements $b$ that may not be in $C_0$ until you exhaust the elements of $A$. You can make this more precise by noting that the cardinality of $A$ strictly decreases if you remove the set $\{a,\sigma a,\dots,\sigma^{n-1}a\}$, so in particular the operation of picking a new $b$ can only be repeated finitely many times.

Comment: The cycle structure of a permutation pops up when you consider the natural action of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ on the set $A$.